# How make a correct query from pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using `pymongo` to subset a collection in mongodb, I am having problems with the syntax of the query, this is my query:

```
import pymongo
client=pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db=client("publications")
collec=db("zikaVirus2")

pipeline=db.collec.aggregate([
   {"$match":{"fullText":{"$exists": "true"}}},
   {"$out": "pub_fulltext"}
])

db.pub_fulltext.aggregate(pipeline)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genColFulltext.py", line 3, in <module>
    db=client("publications")
TypeError: 'MongoClient' object is not callable
```

> **UPDATE 1**

If I do

```
import pymongo
client=pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db=client.publications
collec=db.zikaVirus2

pipeline=db.collec.aggregate([
{"$match":{"fullText":{"$exists": "true"}}},
{"$out": "pub_fulltext"}
])

db.pub_fulltext.aggregate(pipeline)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genColFulltext.py", line 11, in <module>
    db.pub_fulltext.aggregate(pipeline)
  File "/home/danielo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo    /collection.py", line 2397, in aggregate
**kwargs)
  File "/home/danielo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2242, in _aggregate
    common.validate_list('pipeline', pipeline)
  File "/home/danielo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 428, in validate_list
    raise TypeError("%s must be a list" % (option,))
TypeError: pipeline must be a list
```

> **UPDATE 2**

This code runs without problems, but it make nothing of his purpose, the collection `pub_fulltext` have anything, when it should have data.

```
import pymongo
client=pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db=client.publications
collec=db.zikaVirus2

pipeline=db.collec.aggregate([
{"$match":{"fullText":{"$exists": "true"}}},
{"$out": "pub_fulltext"}
])
for item in pipeline:
    db.pub_fulltext.aggregate(item)
```

Then I try this:

```
import pymongo
client=pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db=client.publications
collec=db.zikaVirus2

pipeline=[db.collec.aggregate([
{"$match":{"fullText":{"$exists": "true"}}},
{"$out": "pub_fulltext"}
])]
for item in db.collection.aggregate(pipeline):
    db.collection.aggregate(item)
```

Getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genColFulltext.py", line 10, in <module>
    for item in collection.aggregate(pipeline):

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "genColFulltext.py", line 10, in <module>
for item in db.collection.aggregate(pipeline):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2397, in aggregate
**kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2304, in _aggregate
client=self.__database.client)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 584, in command
self._raise_connection_failure(error)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 745, in _raise_connection_failure
raise error   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 579, in command
unacknowledged=unacknowledged)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 114, in command
codec_options, ctx=compression_ctx)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 679, in _op_msg
flags, command, identifier, docs, check_keys, opts) bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x1008e4198>
```

Comment: You forgot comma after `{"$match":{"fullText":{"$exists": "true"}}}` line

Comment: @Sanya I update a new error that I am getting.

Comment: try `db = client.publications` and `collec = db.zikaVirus2`. And do only `collec.aggregate`, not `db.collec.aggregate`

Comment: @Sanya I update with an new error with that

Comment: You already get the correct pipeline here: `pipeline=db.collec.aggregate([`. Now you can work with it: `for item in pipeline: print(item)`

Comment: @Sanya it works fine but don't do anything. I update the questions, thanks for the feedback

Comment: what exactly you want to reach? your last example you tried does not have any sense to me...

Comment: @RichieK I want to create a new collection "col_b" from other collection "col_a" only if the objects in "col_a" have the field "fullText".